# How to get a list of ObjectID from SearchString for Get-MsolContact

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I have a .csv list of SMTP addresses of contacts that I need to delete. In order to do so, I need to get the ObjectId property for each by powershell, and then export those ObjectIds to a new .csv.

I have tried to retrieve a list of ObjectIds per my CSV using:

$contacts = Import-Csv -path C:\contacts.csv
Get-MsolContact -SearchString $contacts | Select ObjectId

Instead of listing the ObjectId's relevant to the SMTP addresses in the CSV file, it lists the ObjectId's for all contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple rows in the CSV, you will need to complete a search for each user. You will need to add some kind of export or action to the object IDs you get.

```
$contacts = Import-Csv -path C:\contacts.csv 

Foreach($User in $contacts) {
    Get-MsolContact -SearchString $User.SMTPAddress | Select ObjectId
}
```

This assumes your CSV header is SMTPAddress, example:

```
NAME   SMTPAddress
----   -----------
John   John.Doe@contoso.com
Jane   Jane.Smith@contoso.com
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I just added a variable to export-CSV:

$contacts = Import-Csv C:\DeleteContacts.csv 

$data = Foreach($User in $contacts) {
    Get-MsolContact -MaxResults 1820 -SearchString $User.SMTPAddress | Select ObjectId 
}

$data | Export-CSV c:\objectid.csv -NoTypeInformation